How to prove that for algebraic closure of finite field if polynomial is injective then its bijective?
Hi basically I would like to prove Ax–Grothendieck theorem, it says:

If there is a polynomial of complex number $p:\mathbb{C}^n\to\mathbb{C}^n$
If for any  $\vec{x}_1\in\mathbb{C}^n,\vec{x}_2\in\mathbb{C}^n$ that $\vec{x}_1\ne\vec{x}_2$ we have $p(\vec{x}_1)\ne p(\vec{x}_2)$
Then we have for any $\vec{a}\in\mathbb{C}^n$ there exists $\vec{x}\in\mathbb{C}^n$ so that $\vec{a}=p(\vec{x})$

It uses property of ACF theorem to prove this, but before applying that, I need to prove that for finite field, we have:

If $F$ is a finite field, then $F^n$ is finite. In this case the theorem is true for trivial reasons having nothing to do with the representation of the function as a polynomial: any injection of a finite set to itself is a bijection. When F is the algebraic closure of a finite field, the result follows from Hilbert's Nullstellensatz.

I do not understand the prove for "algebraic closure of a finite field", I tried to read Hilbert's Nullstellensatz but cannot find a clue to prove it.
Thus if anyone can help or give me some more guide.

Update: What I'm thinking is that if I really need the Hilbert's Nullstellensatz to prove it?
Now lets  assume that we have a finite field $F$ and its algebraic closure $K$
There is a polynomial projection $P:K^n\to K^n$ so that:

for any $(a_1,...,a_n)\in K^n$ we have that $P(a_1,...,a_n)=(b_1,...,b_n)$
each $b_i$ has an company polynomial $f_i(x_1,...,x_n)\in K[x_1,...,x_n]$ such that for any $(a_1,...,a_n)\in K^n$ we have $f_i(a_1,...,a_n)=b_i$

Now we assume that there is $(z_1,...,z_n)\in K^n$ that for any $(a_1,...,a_n)\in K^n$ we have $P(a_1,...,a_n)\ne(z_1,...,z_n)$
Then we expand the limited field $F$ with:

$z_1,...,z_n$
all the coefficient of $f_i(x_1,...,x_n)\in K[x_1,...,x_n]$ for all $1\leq i\leq n$

Denote all of the above as set $S$, it is obviously that:

$S$ is limited since all $z_i$ and coefficients has a count
$S$ is algebraically over $F$ since $S\subset K$

Now if I'm not wrong, field expansion  with a limited, algebraic set also has a limited dimension. Which means there is a limited set $V=\{v_1,...,v_m\}\subset F_{(S)}$ so that every element $a\in F_{(S)}$ can be expressed as $a=\sum_{i=1}^mc_iv_i$ where $v_i\in F$
Thus $F_{(S)}\subset V\times F$ obviously is also limited, thus:

Since $F_{(S)}$ is also a field and containing all coefficients of $f_i$, so for all $(a_1,...,a_n)\in F_{(S)}^n$ we have $f_i(a_1,...,a_n)\in F_{(S)}$ for all $1\leq i\leq n$. Therefore we can have $P$ limited on $F_{(S)}$ is also a valid function, denote as $P_{|F_{(S)}}:F_{(S)}^n\to F_{(S)}^n$
Since $F_{(S)}\subset K$, so $P_{|F_{(S)}}$ is also injective
Since for any $(a_1,...,a_n)\in K^n$ we have $P(a_1,...,a_n)\ne(z_1,...,z_n)$, we also have for any $(a_1,...,a_n)\in F_{(S)}^n$ we have $P_{|F_{(S)}}(a_1,...,a_n)\ne(z_1,...,z_n)$
Since $F_{(S)}$ is limited, $n<\infty$ then we have $F_{(S)}^n$ is also limited
Since $z_i\in S\subset F_{(S)}$ so  $(z_1,...,z_n)\in F_{(S)}^n$

All of the above is indicating that on a limited domain, $P_{|F_{(S)}}$ is injective but not surjective, which is impossible.

the connection is explained here — the idea is that if it fails in the algebraic closure, it also has to fail in some finite subfield

This is an answer to the question, not just a comment. Please notice that comments should only be used to clarify, not answer the question. See How do comments work for more information. Therefore, I suggest to post your answer as an answer. This brings extra visibility to the answer und puts the question off the unanswered list.

@sassatelligiulio mistake corrected, thanks! and sorry for the late reply since I'm still trying to figure out why

What do you mean by Fn, Shore?

@gerrymyerson sorry, it should be F^n ......

So, it should be $F^n$.

@gerrymyerson yep thanks for pointing it out. btw if I may ask why I need Nullstellensatz to prove it

I don't know, sorry.

@gerrymyerson thanks anyway :)
